# Why is my resolve message not showing up in Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm doing this bascic Promise code,, but my console prints out as " *this is in the then NaN*" instead of the resolve message *"Success"*. I don't know know what's wrong? Can anyone help me? Thank you so much!

This is my JS:

```js
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let a = 1 + 1
    if (a == 2) {
        resolve('Success')
    } else {
        reject('Failed')
    }
})

p.then((message) => {
    console.log('this is in the then ', +message)
}).catch((message) => {
    console.log('this is in the catch ', +message)
})
```

Comment: just remove the +. It tries to parse the variable to a number. You can either console.log(sting, var) or .log(string + var) and not both

Answer (score 2):

Either remove `,` or `+` in your `console.log` statements

```
console.log('this is in the then ' + message)
```

`+message` tries to coerce `message` to a number and hence `NaN`.

```js
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let a = 1 + 1
  if (a == 2) {
    resolve('Success')
  } else {
    reject('Failed')
  }
})

p.then((message) => {
  console.log('this is in the then', message)
}).catch((message) => {
  console.log('this is in the catch', message)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `console.log('this is in the then ', +message)`

`+message` means `+success`, you are trying to convert `success` to a number hence NaN

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways to fix this.

By adding the comma after your quote mark in the string,

```
  console.log('this is in the then ', +message)
```

you're saying that you want to print this string and then ADD (mathematically) message, as opposed to concatenate the string. This errors out because javascript tries to coerce message into a number and can't because it's not valid (hence NaN)

you can rewrite by moving the commas into the quote marks the commas like this

```
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
let a = 1 + 1
if (a == 2) {
    resolve('Success')
} else {
    reject('Failed')
}
})

p.then((message) => {
console.log('this is in the then, ' +message)
}).catch((message) => {
console.log('this is in the catch, ' +message)
})
```

or, arguably nicer syntax is to use a template string like this

```
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
let a = 1 + 1
if (a == 2) {
    resolve('Success')
} else {
    reject('Failed')
}
})

p.then((message) => {
console.log(`this is in the then,  ${message}`)
}).catch((message) => {
console.log(`this is in the catch,  ${message}`)
})
```